# Are $\Bbb{R}$ and $\Bbb{Z}\times\Bbb{R}$ isomorphic as groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

If $\phi:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{Z}\times\Bbb{R}$ be group isomorphism. Then $\phi(1)=(n,x)$ for some $n\in\Bbb{Z},x\in\Bbb{R}$. Then $2n\phi(1/2n)=(n,x)\implies n=0\implies \phi(1)=(0,x)$

Now since $\phi$ is onto there is $y\in\Bbb{R}$ such that $\phi(y)=(1,0)$. It's easy to see that $y$ should be irrational.

I cannot proceed further, can anyone provide me an idea how to prove/disprove the statement?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Every nonzero element in $\mathbb{R}$ is twice someone. Is $(1,0)$ in $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{R}$ twice someone?

Comment: Since an answer has already been given, and I don't like to give answers that are too simple, here's a simpler approach, in a comment. Suppose $\varphi:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{R}$ is a group isomorphism. Let $\varphi(x)=(1,0)$, then if $\varphi(x/2)=(a,b)\in\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{R}$, we must have that $2(a,b)=(1,0)$, which is impossible. By contradiction, $\varphi$ cannot be an isomorphism.

Comment: @C-RAM the posted answer is incorrect.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin You're right; I should have payed more attention. What I wrote is still too simple for me to post in good conscience. I'll let someone with less objections to posting simple answers write up an answer.

Comment: @C-RAM I did. The answer has been deleted as of this writing. I posted the same idea in a comment myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $$\varphi\colon \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$ is an isomorphism.

Let $\varphi(1,0) = x\in \mathbb{R}$. By surjectivity there exists a $(a,b)\in \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{R}$ such that $\varphi(a,b) = \frac{x}{2}$. So we have:
\begin{align*}
     \varphi(1,0) = x = 2\varphi(a,b) = \varphi(2a,2b)    
\end{align*}
By injectivity we have $(1,0) = (2a,2b)$. So $2a = 1$, but $a\in \mathbb{Z}$ which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb R$ is a [divisible group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisible_group), wheras $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb R$ is not.

Answer (score -4):

$\mathbb Z$ is a homomorphic image of $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb R$; the projection map $(x,y)\mapsto x$ is a homomorphism.

$\mathbb Z$ is not a homomorphic image of $\mathbb R$, since the positive sentence $\forall x\exists y(y+y=x)$ is true in $\mathbb R$ but not in $\mathbb Z$.

Therefore $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb R$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb R$, nor even a homomorphic image of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Why the downvotes?